# Сортировка файла php

Tags: php

У меня в файле есть текст по такому типу:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы было:

```
1:2
3:4
```

Comment: в чем проблема то возникла у вас при решении задача? начните с того чтобы с файла данные в массив считать

Comment: @teran я занёс в массив, но не знаю, как отсортировать по Четному / Нечётному

Comment: в вашем примере сортировка отсутствует вообще. тут цикл через 1 элемент, и на каждой итерации берется `i`-й и `(i-1)`-й элементы/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим, вы прочитали файл с помощью функции [file()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php) в массив $arr:

```
$arr = file('file_name.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Далее полученный массив передаёте первым аргументом в функцию [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php), а во втором аргументе указываете количество элементов массива, которые надо получить:

```
array_chunk($arr, 2)
```

Ну и далее обрабатываете результирующий массив с помощью [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php), а в теле её анонимной функции объединяете пару элементов каждого массива через символ двоеточия, с помощью функции [join()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.join.php):

```
join(':', $a);
```

Решение в сборе занимает всего две строки, ну и плюс ваш массив - всё вместе выглядит так:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4]; // прочитать файл в массив с помощью file();

$arr = array_map(function($a){ return join(':', $a); }, array_chunk($arr, 2));

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '1:2' (length=3)
  1 => string '3:4' (length=3)
```